# MySQL Online Judge with Node js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, codeigniter

So I had some experience with online judge (website), some of its using java/c++ and when someone uploads and execute a script, it returns the comparison result with the test cases held in the server.

Anyway, I wanted to make a system which can compare a MySQL select syntax from user, getting the result (array/object) as a text, and compare it with the result of server's MySQL syntax execution, which also returns the result as text, and then doing some grading from it.

I planned on using node js and codeigniter/laravel on this system, and would love to made it works, but i don't know where to start because this is my first try project using node js

As far, I'm able to create a connection to MySQL using node js, and also some basic sql queries. But still no idea on how make things working, like :

- How the user will input the query
- Where the database will be stored
- Can the system receive lots of the query execution comparison inputs from lots of different user

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Wny Node *and* Laravel? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I believe node had the ability to do the server execution thing. I've done this in php, and wanted to try it using node

Comment: Yes, Node does. Is doesn't make sense to use *both* is what I'm saying.

Comment: Well I prioritize in node, so framework is actually optional